# How to correctly verify availability of google play services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google play services availability is verified in `onResume`:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    verifyGooglePlayServicesAvailability()
}
```

The dialog from `getErrorDialog` is show if the check fails:

```
availability.getErrorDialog(this, status, RESOLVE_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_UNAVAILABILITY_REQUEST).show()
```

But for some reason the dialog is shown again one after the error is resolved. I could not find an example of how to implement the checks in the documentation. This is my approach:

```
private fun verifyGooglePlayServicesAvailability()
{
    val availability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val status = availability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        availability.getErrorDialog(this, status, RESOLVE_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_UNAVAILABILITY_REQUEST).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because a Dialog takes foreground and puts the Activity in the background so your onResume is called multiple times. Consider moving it to your onCreate or if you need it in OnResume consider a flag to avoid checking twice if handled